# Does taxation of Treasury Inflation Protected Securities (TIPS) undermine their function as protection against inflation?

Tags: united-states, taxes, bonds, inflation, government-bonds

From [this document](https://personal.vanguard.com/pdf/flgpt.pdf) from Vanguard:

> TIPS are taxed in a slightly different manner than
>   conventional Treasury bonds. The periodic inflation-based
>   “gross-up” in the principal of TIPS is taxed
>   at the ordinary income tax rate, rather than at the
>   lower capital gains rate. These taxes are payable
>   every tax year regardless of the investor’s holding
>   period. If the sale price of a TIPS bond exceeds the
>   inflation-adjusted principal, ordinary capital gains tax
>   rates are applied. As with conventional Treasuries, the
>   inflation-adjusted TIPS coupon payments are taxed at
>   ordinary income tax rates.

Hypothetically let's suppose inflation jumps up to 100% next year and my current marginal tax rate is 40%. If I keep X dollars in cash, next year I'll have X/2 in today's money. If I keep the same amount in TIPS, then I'll have, again in today's money, (1/2)(X+0.6X)=(4/5)X.

In other words, inflation will still destroy a certain portion of my funds -- even if I keep them in TIPS. Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

If the TIPS are held in a taxable account, yes. However, if the TIPS are held in a tax-advantaged account such as an IRA, then the taxation may be different as a Roth IRA may not have any gains taxed as something to consider here.